# PHP MySQL data type insertion error through ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have inserted data through ajax and data inserted but giving error [Error:

```
INSERT INTO jobify_user (u_name,u_phonenumber,u_email,u_password) VALUES 

('','','','')
```

> [1]Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'u_phonenumber' at row 1]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobify_user (u_name,u_phonenumber,u_email,u_password)

  VALUES ('$username','$userphonenumber','$useremail','$userpassword')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

   echo "New record created successfully";

   } else {

     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

   }
```

Comment: Maybe $userphonenumber isn't a number ? Do you have a filter_var or is_numeric to check that it's only numbers ?

Comment: You're passing a string by using the quotes around `$userphonenumber`

Comment: you can use PDO prepared statements with parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `('','','','')` part is the values you are trying to insert into the database.  seeing how all four are empty strings, it seems like the variables $username, $userphonenumber, $useremail, and $userpassword are empty.

Plus, the '' mark the values as string, but the error message you got shows the data type for the u_phonenumber column is integer. You should either change your statement to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobify_user (u_name,u_phonenumber,u_email,u_password)
VALUES ('$username',$userphonenumber,'$useremail','$userpassword')";
```

OR leave the statement the same and change the data type of the u_phonenumber in the database table to VARCHAR.

(Stuff I've seen people enter in "phone number" fields includes: phone numbers starting with + because they included the international prefix; spaces, hyphens or slashes between area code and actual phone number; hyphens or spaces between phone number and extensions; a list of several phone numbers with commas and spaces in between. So I'd tend to making u_phonenumber a VARCHAR.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobify_user (u_name,u_phonenumber,u_email,u_password)

  VALUES ('".$username."','".$userphonenumber."','".$useremail."','".$userpassword."')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

   echo "New record created successfully";

   } else {

     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

   }
```